# How can I export all my Salesforce Community data?

Tags: community, data-export, migration-tool, migration, data-migration

My team is currently attempting to migrate out of Salesforce Community, but we are having a really hard time figuring out how we could:

1. Export all discussions
2. Export all users

The documentation for this was really hard to find, perhaps because community discussions are just a specific instance of a more generic "chatter" type?

I am still a newbie in Salesforce, but after reading dozens of docs I couldn't figure it out. Would really appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

This question is broad so it will likely be closed but to give you a direction to look at:

You should look at `FeedItem`, `FeedPost` and `FeedComment`. [This](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/RelationshipsOfChatterObjects.htm) ERD will be helpful. The feeditems can also point to a ContentDocument.

An ETL tool would be helpful in this scenario. We did a similiar migration with Talend free ETL (not endorsing it, you can use anything else).

---

[image]